Enlarge chart on hover
This visual is made up of multiple area marks arranged vertically.

Besides the middle area mark (GOOG) the others are hard to see without making them larger.  Is it possible to hover over an area mark and make it 2x larger and the others smaller to compensate?
If it is not possible using a row encoding, could it be done with a vconcat of multiple marks?
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 40,
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "mark": "area",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "title": "Time",
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "price",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "title": "Price",
      "axis": {"grid": false}
    },
    "color": {
      "field": "symbol",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": null
    },
    "row": {
      "field": "symbol",
      "type": "nominal",
      "title": "Symbol"
    }
  }
}



Hi @Vlad, Just a tip when looking at ONE stock price is good. when comparing MULTIPLE use percentage change to actually compare.

That's a good tip.  In my actual use case I'm not using stock prices, this was just an example I found in the gallery that had multiple charts aligned vertically.

this should be possible with the some vegaEmbed code. If you want it done within VL spec then you could a "detail" h/v concat chart. when a small chart is clicked then big chart is populated based on filter.

Here is an example when you can click on a legend and the "detail" chart on the right will be filtered based on that param.This functionality is very cool and not often used in many examples.
You can also base it on a chart click but the click must be on the actual area which can be tricky for the user. Change bind to scales instead of legend to test this.
I use this technique often to re-sort a stacked bar chart. The clicked legend item gets moved to the bottom of the stack so you can better see that particular trend.

{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "hconcat": [
    {
      "width": 300,
      "height": 40,
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "user_selected",
          "select": {"type": "point", "fields": ["symbol"]},
          "on": "click",
          "clear": "click",
          "bind": "legend"
        }
      ],
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "title": "Time",
          "axis": {"grid": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Price",
          "axis": {"grid": false}
        },
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"},
        "row": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal", "title": "Symbol"}
      }
    },
    {
      "width": 300,
      "height": 290,
      "transform": [
        {"filter": {"selection": "user_selected"}},
        {"joinaggregate": [{"op": "min", "field": "symbol", "as": "Counter"}]},
        {"filter": "datum.Counter == datum.symbol"}
      ],
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "title": "Time",
          "axis": {"grid": false}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "Price",
          "axis": {"grid": false}
        },
        "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
      }
    }
  ]
}

